# SQL stored procedure - fixed column data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Sir, I have a table in SQL with following data.

```
  ID    Date       Rly   Equipment     Type     
  1  3-Apr-12      SR     SIV       R
  2  3-Apr-12      SER    TM        I
  3  3-Apr-12      NR     3PH       I
  4  3-Apr-12      NCR    3PH       R
  5  3-Apr-12      WR     ARNO      I
  6  3-Apr-12      WR      EMC      I
  7  3-Apr-12      SR      EMC      R
  8  3-Apr-12      SR     Pn. Pipeline   I
```

I am using a pivot statement in SQL for count equipments in Rlys like this

```
 Equipment         SER   NR   NCR  WR   SR    TTL 
  SIV                                    1     1
  TM                1                          1
  3PH                     1    1               2
  EMC                               1    1     2
  ARNO                              1          1
  Pn. Pipeline                           1     1
```

With using this i am facing a problem that whenever an equipment is not appearing in the data table will not appear in pivot statement. But my requirement that each equipment will be appeared in the pivot table wheather available in the main data table or not so that table row be fixed always. Please help so that equipment name in left side column be fixed. For e.g. SIV, TFP & Bearing are not in main data table but required in final result.

Comment: Do you have a source of all of the equipment you want to appear?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stored procedure code and capabilities are very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given you must know what equipment exists from some other table, create your pivot from a left join of equipment to data

ie: if your query currently looks something like

```
select equipment, ser, nr, ncr, wr, sr
from 
(select rly, equipment from #data ) as source
pivot
(count(rly) for rly in ([ser], [nr], [ncr], [wr], [sr])) as p
```

and your equipment table is #eq, then change your query to

```
select eqcode, ser, nr, ncr, wr, sr
from
(select rly, eqcode from #eq left join #data on #eq.eqcode=#data.equipment) as source
pivot
(count(rly) for rly in ([ser], [nr], [ncr], [wr], [sr])) as p
```

Comment: Yes Sir, all equipments are already defined and submitted by User with the help of drop down list.  I am using SQL server 2008.